# Simple function not working on frontend and can't figure a way to debug it

Tags: redirect

I'm trying this ultra-simple snippet on my functions.php on 2020 theme, but it doesn't work

```php
function simple_redirect() {

    if ( is_page(199) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'loop_start', 'simple_redirect' );
```

I've tried many hooks, `wp_head`, `init`, `admin_init`… none of them, show anything in the page with ID 199

PS: I have disabled all plugins and given is a default theme (2020).

Answer (score 1):

`loop_start` is too late

`template_redirect` did the trick.